# Necesito recorrer todo los checkbox icheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

tengo  varios checkbox dentro de una tabla necesito, recorrer la tabla fila x fila, y verificar si los checkbox estan o  no seleccionador, utilizo el plugin icheck para mejorar la apriencia de lo checkbox, pero no puedo manejar este plugin y no se como obtener si estan seleccionados o no, este es el [plugin](http://icheck.fronteed.com/#features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

muy interesante el plugin.
Por ejemplo, la siguiente linea de codigo, lista todos los checkboxs:

```
$('.icheckbox_square-blue')
```

Pero si quieres obtener solo los que estan seleccionados, puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.icheckbox_square-blue.checked')
```

NOTA: Puedes ejecutar en la consola del browser, en la pagina del plugin y puedes comprobar que funciona.

Saludos, espero que te sirva.

Comment: tengo la sieguiente funcion, quiero saber si el checkbox esta seleccionado                                                                              
 function guardar() {
            $('#table_permission tr').each(function (index, element) {
                var elemento = $(element).find("td").eq(3);
                elemento.iCheck('check');
            });
        }